# How can I use Android InputMethodService to send key events from my other service?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to write a simple rest service to use with my Shield TV. It will listen for HTTP requests on a TCP port and then send key events to the activity which is active.

The rest service side is ready. I can call the endpoint and start applications on the Shield TV.
However, since I don't have an activity I am not able to send key events. 
(When I have my activity on the screen it works)

So I decided to register my app as an Input Method. I am able to show my app as a virtual keyboard on Android system input settings.

This is the tutorial that I followed:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html

But I could not figure out how to send key events using the Input Method service. I tried using following code in onCreate method of the InputMethod Service.
However, onCreate does not seem to be called. Because websocket is not active.
(When I use this code on my own service and if I start the service from MainActivity, websocket is active)

public class SoftKeyboard extends InputMethodService {

```
private InputMethodManager mInputMethodManager;

@Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    AsyncHttpServer server = new AsyncHttpServer();
    List<WebSocket> _sockets = new ArrayList<WebSocket>();
    server.get("/test", new HttpServerRequestCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onRequest(AsyncHttpServerRequest request, AsyncHttpServerResponse response) {

            getCurrentInputConnection().sendKeyEvent(
                    new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
            getCurrentInputConnection().sendKeyEvent(
                    new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
        }
    });
    server.listen(5050);

}
```

}

Maybe I should call a function in the Input Method service from my other service (which is started through the main activity)
But I also could not figure out how to do that.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: You might do better to take a step back and explain what you're trying to do at a higher level.  It seems to me you're over complicating things, and expecting the user to select your app as their default input method is just going to be a non-starter

Comment: What I am trying to do is just sending key events (DPAD right, left, up, down, Volume Up, Down, back , home) to the Shield TV (Android device) But I need to do this through a rest API running on the device. Since it will be a service, I need to use Input Method service. There is no other way of sending key events to the UI (or any app running over it) if the app is not a system app.

Comment: so you did the trick?